# Ruby: sort array of hashes, even though key may not exist

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

In a rails application, I have an array of hashes which I can sort easily with just

```
array_of_hashes.sort_by { |hash| hash[:key_to_sort] }
```

But what if not every array member has a key `:key_to_sort`?  Then the sort will fail "comparison of String with nil failed".  Is there a way to allow the sort to continue?  Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends what you want to do when a hash doesn't have sorting key. I can imagine two scenarios:

1) exclude the hash from sorting

```
arr.delete_if { |h| h[:key_to_sort].nil? }.sort_by { |h| h[:key_to_sort] }
```

2) place the hash at the beginning/end of the array:

```
arr.sort_by { |h| h[:key_to_sort] || REALLY_SMALL_OR_LARGE_VALUE }
```

Comment: **Nice.** Moving the hash to the beginning/end in such a case is what I was thinking, just didn't know how to do it.  In the case of alphabetic, I just used `'A'` to put the missing values up top.

Comment: Oh, and +1 for describing the option to exclude the hash.

Comment: Glad I could help. IMHO it would be better to use "" (an empty string) than "A" for a small string value.

Comment: @LukasStejskal What would be the best thing to use for a high string value?

Comment: @AdrianMann I guess: 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz...' :)

Comment: A more ellegant solution is to use [fetch](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/fetch) like `arr.sort_by { |h| h.fetch(:key_to_sort, REALLY_SMALL_OR_LARGE_VALUE) }`